# Kernel 3.14 not working with ATIProprietary fglrx?

Tags: debian, kernel, amd, fglrx

On my debian laptop I installed kernel 3.14 so I have the alx driver so my ethernet works, I originally had the 3.2 kernel (Debian 7.7). AFter installing the new kernel, gnome3 went back to the "failed to start properly"-mode and startx didnt find the fglrx module .(

Is that a kernel compatibility issue? Can I install lower kernels than 3.14 via apt-get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FGLRX has very poor performance (among other issues, which may include kernel compatibility issues with newer kernels). Heed my advice: You need to use the Open-Source Radeon drivers.

https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo

I'm running Kernel 3.14+ on an ATI Radeon 5770HD with the Open-Source drivers.

The solution is not to downgrade your kernel. Download the **Open-Source** drivers via apt-get from the provided link. The XServer should pretty much take care of itself when you install the new packages.

Comment: do I have to have the original proprietary driver installed? Or can I just reinstall Debian, upgrade the kernel and install the FOSS drivers?

Comment: You can remove the original proprietary driver. You can also reinstall Debian, drop-in replace/upgrade the kernel, and then install the FOSS drivers. It's pretty much up to you, mate. When I did my replacement, I chose not to remove the original proprietary driver. If you do remove the original proprietary driver, the system should default to a MESA-Direct Rendering Interface driver. From there you can upgrade to one of the 3 available Open-Source drivers. I have had the best experience with the Radeon driver.

Comment: thanks! Will now reinstall Debian and then replace the kernel and install FOSS drivers^^

Comment: I installed it and it works w/ gnome, but testing the firmware resulted in this: http://hastebin.com/hahecurafo.vbs  Trying to run "osu!" in wine results in terrible framerates :(

Comment: Yeah... That looks like it is trying to run the nonfree firmware for ATI.

Comment: I'm not too sure of performance under WINE. My best guess without sitting there with you is that the nonfree firmware is causing the issue. I'm sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: i was able to get the thing running with firmware-linux-non_free from wheezy backports

Comment: That makes sense. I'm glad you got it working, mate!